# Substituting the values from the array in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to orginize substitution of array of data on Jquery?

I have array of data in external file like this:

```
var prod = [];
prod[0] = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
prod[1] = ['four', 'five', 'six'];
...
```

In html files I want to paste

```
<tr>
    <td class="prodname">prod[4][1]</td>
    <td class="prodnum">prod[4][2]</td>
    <td class="mprice_el">prod[4][3]</td>
</tr>
```

and by call function `fill();` necessary to substitute data from the array.

I try like this:

```
  function fill(){
    var prodname;
    var prodnum;
    var prodprice;
    $('.prodname').each(function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
            $(this).html(prodname);
        }
    }
}
```

But don't know how to get id from html and compare it with array.

Comment: just a side note: if you are using this for a website that needs to be indexed by search engines (google for example) it won't be able to read your products. I would advice you to use a server side language instead.

Comment: Why not set the HTML like `<td class="prodname" data-key="4" data-subkey="1"></td>`?

Comment: @jeffreydev: I agree that the right thing would be to do it server side, but for what's worth Google does index even pages which use JavaScript.

Comment: use json format to store data

Comment: @Shef even though it indexes the pages, it doesn't index the javascript generated content. afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for something like this (though you would probably want to validate the results):

```
$('.prodname').text(function(i, t){
    var m = t.match(/^prod\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]$/);
    return prod[m[1]][m[2]];
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/anusoj/3

Comment: Another option is `$('.prodname').text(function(i, t){return eval(t);});`, but it give a warning: *"eval is evil"*.

Comment: But it's show error in console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null` How to improve it?

Comment: @Vladimir - that is probably because you have a number that is not in your array (for example, `prod[10000][1]` will probably result in an error). You should check in index against `prod.length` and `prod[i].length`. As I've said, the code is missing error handling...

Comment: I don't found what a problem( id of first element (1) is in array. And when this function ready - after any functions don't work.

Comment: Problem found - spacing before prod[x][x]